# Code running in Codepen does not work on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, local, codepen

Javascript codes work on the codepen, but when I test it with vscode, the shapes do not appear and the download button does not work, so javascript codes do not work.

https://codepen.io/rebelchris/pen/rNevrXg

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const download = document.getElementById('download');

// Cirlce
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

// Triangle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(200, 75);
ctx.lineTo(100, 75);
ctx.lineTo(100, 25);
ctx.fill();

// Hearth
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(75, 40);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(75, 37, 70, 25, 50, 25);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(20, 25, 20, 62.5, 20, 62.5);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(20, 80, 40, 102, 75, 120);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(110, 102, 130, 80, 130, 62.5);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(130, 62.5, 130, 25, 100, 25);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(85, 25, 75, 37, 75, 40);
ctx.stroke();

download.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'download.png';
  link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
  link.click();
  link.delete;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're unable to do it. Below is the code for your reference

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        // Code in CSS part goes here...
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <!-- Code under HTML goes here -->
    <canvas id="canvas" height="200"></canvas>
    <br />
    <button id="download">Download</button>

    <script>
        // Code under Javascript goes here
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const download = document.getElementById('download');

        // Cirlce
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();

        // Triangle
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(200, 75);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 75);
        ctx.lineTo(100, 25);
        ctx.fill();

        // Hearth
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(75, 40);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(75, 37, 70, 25, 50, 25);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(20, 25, 20, 62.5, 20, 62.5);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(20, 80, 40, 102, 75, 120);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(110, 102, 130, 80, 130, 62.5);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(130, 62.5, 130, 25, 100, 25);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(85, 25, 75, 37, 75, 40);
        ctx.stroke();

        download.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.download = 'download.png';
            link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
            link.click();
            link.delete;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no problem with the js code. the problem is this code working on the codepen but not working on my computer

Comment: VSCode is a text-editor, just like Notepad in Windows. You need to save the file as HTML file (maybe `myfile.html`) and open the file in browser (Chrome, Firefox etc.) to be able to see the output.

Comment: yes i tried it now, it worked. But I just need to add the download part to my code, but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const download = document.getElementById('btnDownload');
        download.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'download.png';
        link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
        link.click();
        link.delete;
        });

Comment: (I'm trying to save another canvas)

Comment: I would suggest you read through the docs [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

Comment: carstenschaefer.github.io/DrawerJs/examples/fullscreen I want to add download button to this. I imported the source code into vscode. I tried various download codes but none of them worked.

Comment: Please help me, I promise I won't ask any more questions

Comment: @Myrias are you still struggling with this?

Codepen is different from Visual Studio, it's a tool that runs specific code, but doesn't need a document ready for instance.
If you would run this in Visual Studio, you basically need to make a HTML file where this JavaScript is loaded.

Comment: @Rebelchris the issue is they want to add a download button to the example [here](https://carstenschaefer.github.io/DrawerJs/examples/fullscreen/), the source code of which is [here](https://github.com/carstenschaefer/DrawerJs/blob/master/examples/fullscreen/index.html). The issue is when attempting to run the same file on local machine it doesn't work.

Comment: @Rebelchris Your answer to another question was helpful, thanks again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64878821/interesting-download-error-when-trying-to-download-html-canvas-as-image-with-but