# Interesting download error when trying to download html canvas as image with button

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, download, save

When I first click the button it doesn't work. On my second click it downloads 1 picture. My 3rd click it downloads 2 pictures. On my 4th click it downloads 3 pictures. So
1-0, 2-1, 3-2, 4-3. They are also downloaded immediately, it doesn't ask where to save.

js:

```
  function xyz(){
  const text =canvas.api.getCanvasAsImage();
  const download = document.getElementById('download');
  download.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'download.png';
  link.href = text;
  link.click();
  link.delete;
});
}
```

html:

```
<button  onclick="xyz()" id="download">Download</button>
```

I have just started learning javascript. I'm trying to learn by examining an application. I did not understand why these is happening and therefore could not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are basically doing two things now.

So when someone clicks the button you call the function `xyz`.
In there you attach another click listener so the second time, both `xyz` and that listener will fire.

You can write your `xzy` like this:

```js
function xyz(){
  const text = canvas.api.getCanvasAsImage();
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'download.png';
  link.href = text;
  link.click();
  link.delete;
}
```

This should just download your `download.png` file once every click.

As for the location, this is not default behaviour, it will just download to your downloads, this happens because we force a image download. It's not a user optional thing here.

I hope this makes sense, so be aware when using the `onclick` you don't have to do the binding.

### Optional method

You could however also do this if you would prefer non inline scripts

```html
<button  id="download">Download</button>
```

```js
const text = canvas.api.getCanvasAsImage();
const download = document.getElementById('download');
  
download.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'download.png';
  link.href = text;
  link.click();
  link.delete;
});
```

Hope this helps you! ✌️